# Which is the proper or best way to use i18n with many html tags on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a code like that needs to be added to i18n, and I was wondering which would be the best/safest way to do it, For now I put it as is on i18n and called it on ruby code with a variable and html_safe, but I dont know if it implies any security danger, I also thought of passing the html tags as parameters of those i18n variables

```
<p>Através dos princípios da<strong> economia colaborativa </strong> e do <strong>
      <span id="yellow">poder da tecnologia</span></strong> nosso modelo de negócio
alia a <strong> <span id="green"> expertise do executive search </span></strong>
 <strong><span id="red">, a </span></strong>importância das relações humanas <strong> e o<span id="blue">alcance das redes</span>
```

Comment: I would advise to have separate marketing pages in different languages. And use i18n for rails stuff, not HTML.

Comment: This page in question has only that snippet of HTML, the rest of the page is on ruby, but I wouldn't like to have an exploit point and rewriting all the page for another language would also be a hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have localized snippets for the whole thing instead ([Rails Guides: Localized views](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views)):

**spanish version in own file**

```
# marketing.es.erb
<p>Através dos princípios da<strong> economia colaborativa </strong> e do <strong>
      <span id="yellow">poder da tecnologia</span></strong> nosso modelo de negócio
alia a <strong> <span id="green"> expertise do executive search </span></strong>
 <strong><span id="red">, a </span></strong>importância das relações humanas <strong> e o<span id="blue">alcance das redes</span>
```

and then **the english one**

```
# marketing.en.erb
<p>Something<strong> in english</strong>...  <strong>
      <span id="yellow">... </span></strong>
```

And automatically include the correct partial

```
(other content)
<%= render :marketing %>
```